# java.lang.NullPointerException on JSON GET request with Volley

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception, get, android-volley

I'm trying to send a GET request passing a authentication token header to get some JSON data however I'm getting java.lang.NullPointerExceptions all over the place. I already tried with JSONObjectRequest, JSONArrayRequest and even as a StringRequest.

Here's the code (JSONObjectRequest and JSONArrayRequest are commented for tests):

```
 public void getJSON() {

    final String authToken = getAuth();
    String novaURL = getNova();
    novaURL = novaURL+"/servers";


    /**
___________________________________________________________________
    JsonArrayRequest getRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(novaURL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("Nova", response.toString());
                    setNovaJSON(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("Nova", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
    }
    ){
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("X-Auth-Token", authToken);
            params.put("Accept", "application/json");
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return params;
        }
    };


    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(getRequest);

}

    JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, novaURL, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray servers = response.getJSONArray("servers");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error to get Instances", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Log.d("Nova", response.toString());
                    setNovaJSON(response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("Nova", "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                }
            }
    ) {
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("X-Auth-Token", authToken);
            params.put("Accept", "application/json");
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return params;
        }

    };
 ________________________________________________________________ **/

    StringRequest getRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            novaURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("Nova", response.toString());
            setNovaJSON(response.toString());


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("Nova", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }) {
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("X-Auth-Token", authToken);
            params.put("Accept", "application/json");
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(getRequest);

}
```

The exception happens at this line:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

> 11-20 13:44:28.623  14599-14599/com.x.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
>   11-20 13:44:28.623  14599-14599/com.x.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41642ce0)
>   11-20 13:44:28.643  14599-14599/com.x.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.stackerz.app, PID: 14599
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.content.ContextWrapper.getCacheDir(ContextWrapper.java:230)
>               at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:43)
>               at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:78)

It's hard to find out what's happening because the error is not very descriptive. I apologize in advance if it's too obvious but this is my very first app and I just can't get it to work. I'd really appreciate some help.

**UPDATE:

I might have found something useful. I moved the line "RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);" to the top of the method with the other variables declaration and after debugging it seems it crashes right there even before getting to the JSONObjectRequest or StringRequest commands. It seems there's a problem with the queue.

**UPDATE2:

I manage to fix the queue problem adding a Singleton class extending Application (also had to add it to the Manifest as Application instead of Activity) following the steps here: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html

However I'm still getting exceptions:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
```

During debug I noticed it jumps straight from the "getRequest" declaration (no matter if it's JSONObjectRequest, JSONArrayRequest or StringRequest) to the Response.ErrorListener(). Looks like it doesn't even try to connect to the URL. I tested the connection to the URL from a REST browser and confirmed it works fine, generating the JSON output.

Comment: Are you sending the request in side a activity or fragment ? if fragment the do this  Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity())

Comment: Try to pass your activity reference to getJSON() and use this activity reference instead of this.

Comment: I'm sending it from an Activity however the connection is triggered from a NavigationDrawer fragment. Can it be causing the issue?

Comment: Basically the MainActivity calls "instances = NovaJSON.shared().receiveData(novaURL, authToken);" which is a method in the NovaJSON class/activity then sends the URL and the Token to the getJSON() method. I can confirm the URL and Token strings get to the method successfuly however Volley crashes after trying to connect the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All fixed adding a Singleton class extending Application (also had to add it to the Manifest as Application instead of Activity) following the steps here: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html

The other exception was caused because the async connection on volley was taking too long. I fixed by calling the method earlier in the load of the app, giving time for volley to do its thing.

Answer (score 2):

it seems the **Volley.newRequestQueue(this)**'s "this" was null.

Comment: Just double checked, it's not null:
this = com.stacrz.app.NovaJSON@42162e58

Answer (score 0):

There must something wrong with the code

```
Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
```

The method signature is bolow：

```
public static RequestQueue newRequestQueue(Context context) {
    return newRequestQueue(context, null);
}
```

So,the this you passed should be a Context like a activity instance,or a application context.Application context is much better.

Comment: The problem was actually the request queue. I created an application class called VolleySingleton and changed the call to the queue pointing to a method in the new class:

queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
queue.add(getRequest);

Answer (score 0):

Add your singleton class name in manifeast application tag

**Singleton Class**

```
class VolleyApplication extends Application {
----
----
}
```

**Manifeast**

```
<application
    android:name=".VolleyApplication"  --> Add this line
    ...>
    ...
</application>
```